# Liferay Screen DDLListScreenlet Shows "Error loading list"

Tags: android, liferay, liferay-6

I have Recently started developing android mobile apps for Liferay 6.2.

The DDLListScreenlet show error loading list. here is my code. I am stuck here with displaying the ddl lists. I have done it as given in this video [DDLListScreenlet Demo](https://youtu.be/A_QEZzkuGHg). I have Checked well, recordSetId and lableFields are correct.

activity_ddllist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:liferay="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.mindcraft.myspace.DDLListActivity">

    <include android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <com.liferay.mobile.screens.ddl.list.DDLListScreenlet
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        liferay:recordSetId="28285"
        liferay:labelFields="Title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

server_context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- Change these values for your Liferay Portal installation -->

    <string name="liferay_server">http://192.168.0.8:8090</string>

    <integer name="liferay_company_id">20154</integer>
    <integer name="liferay_group_id">20181</integer>

    <integer name="liferay_recordset_id">28285</integer>
    <integer name="liferay_structure_id">28283</integer>
    <string name="liferay_recordset_fields">Title</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Can you post the exception? You have to be logged to show a list also.